# how to create a sub-directory inside an existing parent directory

Tags: php

In my site root I have a directory called **uploaded** and I have another directory called **inc** where i store my functions file.

When  user registers I want to create a sub-directory inside the **uploaded** parent directory.

To my knowledge i have to step out of the **inc** directory using the **../** so i could get into the **uploaded** directory and successfully create the sub-directory inside using the **mkdir()**

I tried this but it does me no good:

```
<?php

$username = "jamesodurojbe";
$root = dirname(__FILE__);
    $dir1 = $root . "../uploaded/$username";
    if(!is_dir($dir1)){
     mkdir($dir1);
    }

?>
```

please help

Comment: `$dir1 = $root . "../uploaded/$username";`   You mean:  `$dir1 = $root . "/../uploaded/$username";` ? Note the leading '/'?

Comment: @RyanVincent .Thank you . Your solution worked. I really find understanding stepping of of directories in php using the ../

Answer (score 0):

Use the third parameter of `mkdir():`

```
$path = '/path/to/folder/with/subdirectory';
mkdir($path, 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to step out of the inc direction with the leading

**/../uploaded/$username**

credit goes to **Ryan Vincent**

The whole code had to look like:

```
//create user account directory folder for uploads
    $root = dirname(__FILE__);
    $dir1 = $root . "/../uploaded/$username";
    if(!is_dir($dir1)){
     mkdir($dir1);
```